# How can i set absolute positions to items on a listView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I created some Activities on my app,so i created a listView with the name of those activities , so i can click on them and open the activity that i want (with setOnClickListener method and switch.) and a i created a searhView, so i can filter them by its name (with setOnQueryTextListener).

Let's use 3 names as examples: Alfred,Beth,Bill

In the "normal" listView Alfred is 0, Beth is 1, Bill is 2. So i made this:

```
switch( position )
                {
                    case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, alfred.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 1:  Intent newActivityy = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, beth.class);
                        startActivity(newActivityy);
                        break;
                    case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, bill.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity2);
                        break;
```

When i search in the searchView for "B" just Beth and Bill appears, and that is right, but now Beth is case 0, and Bill is case 1, so it will not open the activity that i want.

How can i set absolute values to the itens? like Alfred is always 0, Beth always 1 and Bill awalys 2?

Here is my entire code.

```
public class telaPesquisa extends Activity {


    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    String[] teams={

            "Alfred",
            "Beth",
            "Bill",

    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_pesquisa);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,teams);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {




                //nt firstPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()+3;

                int itemPosition = position;





                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                switch( position )
                {
                    case 0:  Intent alfred = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, alfred.class);
                        startActivity(alfred);
                        break;

                    case 1:  Intent beth = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, beth.class);
                        startActivity(beth);
                        break;

                    case 2:  Intent bill = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, bill.class);
                        startActivity(bill);
                        break;


            }
        });






             sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {






                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);



                return false;
            }
        });





    }

}
```

**sorry for my english**

Comment: Why don't you change your switch from `position` to `itemValue` ? i.e: `switch(itemValue) { case : "Beth": //goToBeth; break;}`

Comment: Firstly you're better off creating a single activity and passing the name to it. Secondly if you still insist on having separate activities, instead of checking against position check against the names selected

Comment: @AhmedAbidi Exactly what i wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the listener as this:

```
v.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            switch( itemValue )
            {
                case "alfred":  Intent alfred = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, alfred.class);
                    startActivity(alfred);
                    break;

                case "beth":  Intent beth = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, beth.class);
                    startActivity(beth);
                    break;

                case "bill":  Intent bill = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, bill.class);
                    startActivity(bill);
                    break;
        }
    });
```